# c# add textfile to 2 dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to read a text file, which contains proxys into a 2 dimensional array.

The text file looks like the following:

```
00.00.00.00:80
00.00.00.00:80
00.00.00.00:80
00.00.00.00:80
00.00.00.00:80
```

How could I seperate the ip from the port?`

So my array would look like the following:

[00.00.00.00][80]

**Current code:**

```
public void readProxyList(string FileName)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName, Encoding.Default))
    {
        string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string[] lines = text.Split('\r');

        foreach (string s in lines)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are not expecting the file to be too large you could use [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) to read in each line.  Then to split, just use [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) with ':' as your token.

Example:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(FileName));
var array = new string[lines.Length,2];
for(int i=0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    var temp = lines[i].Split(':');
    array[i,0] = temp[0];
    array[i,1] = temp[1];
}
```

**Edit**

If you expect that the file may be large, instead of using `ReadAllLines` you can use [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx). This method returns an `IEnumerable<string>` and will not read the whole file at once.  In this case, I would probably opt away from the 2d array and make a simple class (call it IpAndPort or something like that) and create a list of those.

Example:

```
public sealed class IpAndPort
{
    public string Ip { get; private set; }
    public string Port { get; private set; }
    public IpAndPort (string ip, string port)
    {
        Ip = ip;
        Port = port;
    }
}

var list = new List<IpAndPort>();
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(FileName))
{
    var temp = line.Split(':');
    list.Add(new IpAndPort(temp[0], temp[1]);
}
```

Comment: You may need a Trim() call to get rid of newlines, no?

Comment: @Levon - From the docs of ReadAllLines - "The resulting string does not contain the terminating carriage return and/or line feed", so I believe it is unnecessary in this case. You could add it to be "safe" or if there was additional whitespace in the lines, but as far as the newlines, they should already be stripped out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public IEnumerable<string> GetProxyList(string FileName)
    {
        string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(FileName);
        var result = new List<string>(allLines.Length);

        foreach (string line in allLines)
        {
            var splittedLine = line.Split(':');
            result.Add($"[{splittedLine[0]}][{splittedLine[1]}]");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: The OP asked for a 2d array, not a single dimensional list containing strings now wrapped in square braces.